# Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic and it's not zero in a domain $\Omega$. Consider the laplace operator, prove that this equality is true

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The laplace operator is the $\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$

And the equality we want is the following $$\Delta(|f(z)|)=\frac{|f'(z)|^2}{|f(z)|}$$

In my attempt to prove this, I setted $z=x+iy$, $f=u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$  and $|f(z)|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ and then calculated $\Delta(\sqrt{u^2+v^2})$ which was a terrible idea, not only it was excruciating to calculate all of this (I'm not putting it here because it was immense), the result was something like

$$\frac{uu_{xx}+u_x+uu_{yy}+vv_{xx}+v_y+vv_{yy}-|f'(z)|^2}{|f(z)|}$$

Which was disappointing to say the least. So I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do this or atleast something to make this process easier. If anyone can help me i would appreciate it a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, this is a great opportunity to use $\partial={\partial\over \partial z}={1\over 2}({\partial\over \partial x}-i{\partial\over \partial y})$ and $\overline{\partial}={\partial\over \partial \overline{z}}={1\over 2}({\partial\over \partial x}+i{\partial\over \partial y})$. The trick is that $\partial$ annihilates anti-holomorphic functions like $\overline{f}$, and $\overline{\partial}$ annihilates holomorphic functions like $f$. So
$$
\Delta(|f|) \;=\; 4\partial\overline{\partial}f^{1/2}\overline{f}^{1/2}
\;=\;
4(\partial f^{1/2})(\overline{\partial}\overline{f}^{1/2})
\;=\; 4\cdot {1\over 2}{f'\over f^{1/2}}\cdot {1\over 2}{\overline{f'}\over \overline{f}^{1/2}}
\;=\; {|f'|^2\over |f|}
$$

Comment: I'm not understanding how can i get the first equality

Comment: The Laplacian is $4$ times the composition of the del and delbar operators, and $|f|=f^{1/2}\cdot \overline{f}^{1/2}$.

Comment: Ok, i got it, but why can we commute in the second equality?

Comment: For $f$ holomorphic and $g$ anti-holomorphic, $\partial(fg)=\partial f\cdot g+f\cdot \partial g=\partial f\cdot g+f\cdot 0$, etc.